# How to know when users login linux machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am pretty much new to linux programming. I want to create a log file with some info when a user just logs in. so where can I find an event or something when a user logs in? is there any structure that has some flag when user logs in?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to know, right now, the last ten logins type `last -10`.

Comment: Have you considered selecting answers on some of your previous questions, if any of the answers are agreeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `utmp` and `wtmp` files contain last login data. [See the man page for more information.](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp)

Comment: thanks but I know the utmp file. So let me put it this way... I boot, then I login & give password. If I already have a background process running how will it know that I just logged in?

Comment: I suppose it could watch the utmp/wtmp files' modification times every second or two or so, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual page for [utmp(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp) and [getutent(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getutent)

The files:

```
   /var/run/utmp
   /var/log/wtmp
```

contain information about who's currently using the system. The wtmp file records all logins and logouts and the utmp file contains information of what kind of login it is, who logged in etc.